# What happens when I reset the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft: XBox 360 Edition, There is an option to reset the Nether. What does this do? Does it generate a "brand new" Nether with a completely different layout, or the same Nether with some additional features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option does build a new Nether, but the more important thing is that it applies all new changes to it like Nether fortress with blaze spawner, so you can get these new materials on your old (before updates) world. As you can imagine with a new build, all the buildings/construction you have will be erased.

Comment: What about the *actual* layout? Like natural landmarks that were present in the old one? Do they stay in the same position as before?

Comment: Do you mean like lava lakes and that stuff? Because the option "discard" your current Nether to build a whole new one, being the point of this to force your new Nether to have all new features that comes with the updates. Hope this helps :). And sorry if it's not what you asking KrymeX, I'm not sure if I understand the landsmark part...

Comment: @Jorge They mean, is the generated landscape new, or just reset to how it was the first time the Nether was visited?

Comment: Ok, thanks @SevenSidedDie, i did not get that :S, and yes the terrain is build from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Reseting the nether will create a brand new nether. Doing this is helpful if your nether doesn't have a nether forteress or any blazes.